# calling sub report not getting any data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have sub report in my crystal report ..i am working on vb.net windows form application..
i given code like this:

```
   Dim rpt As New DelivaryPerformance
        Dim rpt1 As New DelParkingtype
        Dim locid As Integer = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", CmbLocations.Text)
        Dim cmdstatus As New SqlCommand("IBS_DelivaryStaus", con.connect)
        cmdstatus.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdstatus.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        da.SelectCommand = cmdstatus
        da.Fill(ds)
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
            ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        End If
        Dim cmdparkingtype As New SqlCommand("IBS_Delivaryparkingtype", con.connect)
        cmdparkingtype.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdparkingtype.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        da.SelectCommand = cmdparkingtype
        da.Fill(ds)
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            rpt1.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        End If
```

but it only loading my `DelivaryPerformance` report only...how i can call two report the same viewer??
any one know please help me to find out this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use one viewer for both, but not at the same time. Your code sets rpt1 as ReportSource and then replaces it with rpt. So you can use a second viewer or for example use a button that sets the ReportSource.

Comment: give me some more explanation...in this case what i have to change

Comment: You have to change how your reports are display. If you want to see both at the same time use a second viewer.

Comment: sir,,i want to see both same time..so i have to add one more crystal report viewer

Comment: that time how i can show both viewer same time?? at a time that should show one viewer right?